# Play framework 2.x laconic template internationalization

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Does anyone know a more laconic way to internationalization than:

```
<h2>@Messages.get("Title")</h2>
```

Something in the spirit of the Play 1.x:

```
<h2>&{'Title'}</h2>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the standard way. You could create your own tag:

```
//file: I.scala.html under views.tags

@(key: String)

@Messages.get(key)
```

and then use it like

```
@import tags._  //to import tags, only once per template

@I("my.key")
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Pere Villega](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116791/pere-villega)'s answer, I created a small tag file to support message parameters.

`i.scala.html` (because I don't trust uppercase `i`s):

```
@(key: String, args:String*)@Messages(key, args:_*)
```

The file's content is on a single line and doesn't contain any and whitespace in the html part, because otherwise linebreaks would be included and may break something or at least make the resulting code ugly and hard to read.
It can be used like this: `@i("my.key", value1, value2)`.

---

Another tag, `hi.scala.html`, for messages including html:

```
@(key: String, args:String*)@Html(Messages(key, args:_*))
```

Comment: I like this. I also added it to my `templatesImport`.